# Do we need to set object of custom class as null or GC will take care of it

Tags: c#, class, garbage-collection, idisposable

Please have a look at sample code given below. I have two questions:
1. Do we need to close data reader before returning something or GC will take care of it?
2. Do we need to set custom class objects as null or GC will take care of it in these two scenarios?

```
public class Database
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,Name From Person", con))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    return reader["Name"].ToString();
                    //will this close reader once string is returned or we have to close it?
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

USAGE

```
Database database = new Database();
string res = database.DoSomething();
database = null; //is it necessary to do this or GC will take care of it?
```

Another class

```
public class XML
    {
        public void ReadXML()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("somefile.xml");
        }
    }
```

USAGE

```
XML xml = new XML();
xml.ReadXML();
xml = null; //is it necessary to do this or GC will take care of it?
```

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You are missing a `using` statement at the `SqlReader`. The other scenrarions are handled by the GC. Always use `Dispose` or `using` if you are done with objects that implements the `IDisposable` interface (there are a few exceptions on this last note).

*note:*
for a "subtitle" difference in lifetime and scope, see @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment. For more info about the garbage collection see MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx

In general, all managed objects which have no outstanding references, will be taken care of by the GC. So in general, you don't need to explicitly set them to null.

However, if a object implements the `IDisposable` interface, it is preferred to call `Dispose` when you are done with the object. Although (if correctly implemented), this will also be called during the `Finalize` call, it's preferred to call `Dispose` explicit (or through the `using` statement). Objects, like database connections, graphic objects or network-connection can otherwise lead to a full connection pool or occupies graphic memory.

Be advised that this is all about scope and outstanding references.

if you have a method, like this, the `object` "behind" `database`will be taken care of as soon as it leaves the scope because no other variables are referring to this object:

```
public void Foo()
{
   Database database = new Database();
   string res = database.DoSomething();
   //you don't need this call 
   // because the will be no outstanding references after the method exits.
   //database = null;
}
```

But if the containing object is static or kept alive in another way, you'll get this scenario; the `database` is kept alive as long as there is a valid reference somewhere to *that* `FooClass` object:

```
public class FooClass
{
    Database database = new Database();

    public void Foo()
    {  
        //some operation
    }    
}
```

If a member implements `IDisposable` it is best to call it through a `using` statement or explicitly (`Dispose()`). Although the GC should handle this, especially with third party libraries, it requires for `IDisposable` to be correctly implemented. If you see this example, you can see that it can be tricky and therefore is a suspect when facing memory leaks.

[Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

So, to answer your question's scenarios:

In the following, the `using` statement, is equivalent to a `try, catch finaly` block. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

```
public class Database
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,Name From Person", con))
            {
                //note: using a using here as well
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        //this is ok, because the USING will take care of the disposure.
                        return reader["Name"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I think this is enough information to answer the question about the GC. There is one point of attention though; if you are facing *unmanaged objects*, there are other calls necessary for proper disposure. `COM` for example requires `Marshall.ReleaseComObject()`, and some libraries (some industrial camera drivers I know of), require an explicit, `CleanUp` call.

Comment: For your first example, I think you confuse scope and lifetime. Provided you're running in release mode, the JIT compiler and GC collude to understand actual lifetimes. If your commented section actually contains lots of time consuming code but doesn't otherwise make use of `database`, it may be collected whilst `Foo` is still running. Similarly, an object can be collected *whilst its constructor is still running*, provided no actual accesses are potentially in the future.

Comment: Good point; I'll make an edit and reference to your comment. I think my effort to keep it simple introduced some inaccuracies.